# How to authenticate emails to prevent gmail mark it as spam

Tags: asp.net, email, nopcommerce, dkim

We just open a new e-commerce website and recently noticed Gmail treat our e-mails as spam (notice the red question mark). Our website run behind CloudFlare so the email server IP address is different than the domain.

[image: SPAM marked notice the question mark]

We also did not send a bulk email at least not yet. There are some explanations in Google FAQ but not sure what it means or how I need to implement it. Can you please explain how to set these DKIM (preferred) or SPF.

Our website uses nopcommerce (3.70) and developed with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a "pro" at these things (more later):

- IMHO, this is probably the [simplest explanation of `DKIM`](https://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/341.htm)
- `SPF`: in my own words: providing a DNS TXT record that identifies "where" all your emails (smtp/mta servers) can come from. The more complete/formal spec is [here](http://www.openspf.org/)
- You can implement both

---

### Opinionated:

- `SPF` is easier to implement

  - identify all the origins of your email, set them in your `SPF record`, which is a `TXT` record in `DNS`
- `DKIM`: is more complex - *your* mail/smtp server/s must implement it.

  As a "web developer" one can see how this would be done in ASP.Net/C#/VB - e.g. sign some payload and using `HttClient` send some signature in an `HTTP header` in some outbound request.

  But this is done on an SMTP server, so unless you have one that already implements it, it's something you'll have to do...

IMHO, for DKIM, unless your SMTP/MTA implements it, I'd go for services that provide it. There are 2 types:

- *Transactional email* services:

  **Not** for bulk email. These are the usual "order confirmation" emails, standard support/customer service, etc. emails. They will likely have APIs for you to implement (e.g. sending your `MailMessage` using thier servers and/or constructing something that equates to it and send that "object" to their API).
- *Bulk email* services

  these providers will already have implementations because one of their core value propositions is "deliverability" of your **bulk/marketing** emails. They *should* (of course do your due diligence) have both implementations inherently. Will also have their own APIs for bulk email context.

Hth

Comment: OP can use [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/NetworkTools.aspx) to check if those email and (reverse) DNS settings are set up correctly.

Comment: I have added 2 DNS records TXT and SPF in the CloudFlare DNS section with 'v=spf1 ip4:IP_Address_Mail_Sent -all' value. Does this mean mails from this ip address are valid but not the others. 
Is this correct? As you said DKIM is really complicated and I don't think I have that much control over the server as its a shared hosting.

Comment: True @VDWWD, though _if memory serves_, unless you actually have control over your IPs (IINM unless the IPs are ["delegated" to you by net provider](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/managed-dns/domain/setup-reverse-dns/)), _reverse_ DNS isn't that "easy".

Comment: @EdSF, I'm no expert either, but I think you're right that the ISP usually does the reverse DNS with basic hosting solutions. But not having it adds a little more spam score to your email.